# How to place objects in the showcases?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have built a house in Skyrim and I am docorating it. So, I have crafted some showcases but I think it is too complicated to put objects in there.

Is there any easy way to put objects in there?

I've tried to grab the objects and drop in the showcase but the result didn't like me because I can't control the position of the object. p.e. When I grab an axe I always pick it by the handler and the edge is upside down, so, it's too hard to place it properly.

Comment: if you are on the PC you can use the console, but beyond that its impossible

Comment: Carefully. Very carefully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very hard to properly place objects in display cases. And the fact that the items sometimes spawn on the floor beside the case after reloading the area doesn't make it easier.

If you are playing on PC and only want to place weapons in the display cases you can use this mod: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/40400/?

This mod places a invisible weapon stand inside each display case in which aligns the weapon.

Comment: see my comment on the other answer as to why items spawn on the floor after a load.

Answer (score 3):

Much like z said, but I'll elaborate.

If you are playing on PC, you can use console commands to do so. You'll have to spawn the showcase with the item inside of it or spawn the item inside of the showcase.

Other than that option, there is no other way to place things inside showcases without dropping them in there.

More than likely the only advice I can give you is to tell you is **good luck!**

Comment: just to add, if you want to place an item and make sure it says, drop a second item after finishing the placement of the first in order for the placement to 'stick' otherwise it'll lose its positioning the next time the zone loads again.